# Why is my popup broken?

Tags: html, css, jsp, jakarta-ee

My first popup works as expected, pressing the button activates a div that lays over the other elements on the page:

[image]

Then if I change to another popup nothing works. The first way that worked was done like this

`<input type="button" value="S&ouml;k" onClick="getElementById('popupSokNamn').style.display='';">`

Then that activated the JSP include that is in a div

```
<div class="popup" id="popupSokNamn" 
<% if(!showSearch) { %>
style="display: none;"
<% } %>
>
<%@ include file="WEB-INF/jspf/namnuppgifter_sok.jspf" %>
</div>
```

So the other popup should work the same way but of course nothing works since this is HTML and CSS where everything is runtime error and impossible to debug:

```
<input type="button" value="S&ouml;k" onClick="getElementById('popupF').style.display='';">
```

This should render the other popup but of course it doesn't since nothing works.

```
<div class="popup" id="popupF" 
<% if(!showSearchF) { %>
style="display: none;"
<% } %>
>
<%@ include file="includes/fullfoljd_fran_sok.jsp" %>
</div>
```

Why does nothing work? I asked before about this and the answers say it is my CSS but I doubt it since the first popup is loading this ought to be some trivial error somewhere but where?

The last part of the page is where I keep the code for my popups and only one of them works:

```
<div class="popup" id="popupSokNamn" 
<% if(!showSearch) { %>
style="display: none;"
<% } %>
>
<%@ include file="WEB-INF/jspf/namnuppgifter_sok.jspf" %>
</div>
<div class="popup" id="popupSokNamn2" 
<% if(!showSearch2) { %>
style="display: none;"
<% } %>
>
<%@ include file="WEB-INF/jspf/namnuppgifter_sok2.jspf" %>
</div>
<div class="popup" id="popupD" 
<% if(!showSearchD) { %>
style="display: none;"
<% } %>
>
<%@ include file="WEB-INF/jspf/handlaggare_sok.jspf" %>
</div>

<div class="popup" id="popupI" 
<% if(!showSearchI) { %>
style="display: none;"
<% } %>
>
<%@ include file="WEB-INF/jspf/ingivningsdag_sok.jspf" %>
</div>

<div class="popup" id="popupP" 
<% if(!showSearchP) { %>
style="display: none;"
<% } %>
>
<%@ include file="WEB-INF/jspf/prioriteter_sok.jspf" %>
</div>

<div class="popup" id="popupR" 
<% if(!showSearchR) { %>
style="display: none;"
<% } %>
>
<%@ include file="WEB-INF/jspf/rabattgrundande_sok.jspf" %>
</div>

<div class="popup" id="popupF" 
<% if(!showSearchF) { %>
style="display: none;"
<% } %>
>
<%//@ include file="includes/fullfoljd_fran_sok.jsp" %>
</div>
<div class="popup" id="popupA" 
<% if(!showSearchA) { %>
style="display: none;"
<% } %>
>
<%@ include file="WEB-INF/jspf/avdelad_fran_sok.jspf" %>
</div>
<div class="popup" id="popupU" 
<% if(!showSearchU) { %>
style="display: none;"
<% } %>
>
<%@ include file="WEB-INF/jspf/utbruten_fran_sok.jspf" %>
</div>
<div class="popup" id="popupO" 
<% if(!showSearchO) { %>
style="display: none;"
<% } %>
>
<%@ include file="WEB-INF/jspf/omvandlad_ep_sok.jspf" %>
</div>
<div class="popup" id="popupEPa" 
<% if(!showSearchEPa) { %>
style="display: none;"
<% } %>
>
<%@ include file="WEB-INF/jspf/ep_avdelad_fran_sok.jspf" %>
</div>
<div class="popup" id="popupEPn" 
<% if(!showSearchEPn) { %>
style="display: none;"
<% } %>
>
<%@ include file="WEB-INF/jspf/ep_ansokningsnummer_sok.jspf" %>
</div>
</form>
<%@ include file="WEB-INF/jspf/arendeprocess_messages_inc.jspf" %>

<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I can see on the page that the content is actually there but is not displayed and only one popup can be set to visible. I could get the other popup in a state where there was a change to the page and some junk was rendered but in its current state nothing happens when I press the button for the other popup. I can move the activating code to another button and then the same popup will appear from the button but I can't get any of the other popups to display no matter what I do.

Any ideas about this mess?

I keep booleans in the scriptlet of my JSP for the different displays:

```
boolean showSearch = false;
boolean showSearchD = false;
boolean showSearchP = false;
boolean showSearchI = false;
boolean showSearchR = false;
boolean showSearch2 = false;
boolean showSearchF = false; 
boolean showSearchA = false;  
boolean showSearchU = false;  
boolean showSearchO = false;
boolean showSearchEPa = false;
boolean showSearchEPn = false;
```

And neither this seems to be the problem. Please help me troubleshoot!

Comment: You have showSearch in first and showSearchF in second, could that be the problem?

Comment: @Ashwin Singh Thank you for the comment. The page is too complex; both variables showSearch and showSearchF are used and when I try the render the second popup it starts to display but in a broken manner. I can include more info about my problems in the question, updating it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use CSS and set position to absolute for some reason. Then it will work.